# Handling errors using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a call to an API using retrofit to register a user, I want to handle the 401 error when the user enters a phone number or email that already exists or is of the wrong format.

```
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.getType();
                    ErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(),type);
                   Log.d("err", errorResponse.getMessage().getPhone().get(0))
```

The above is my code which  only displays for a single entity like phone..How do i get error message for both the phone and email from the json response

```
{
"status": false,
"message": {
    "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
    ],
    "phone_no": [
        "The phone no has already been taken."
    ]
}
```

}

This is the Json response

```
public class ErrorResponse {
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private Message message;



public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public Message getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

Then the error response

Comment: is it possible for you to display whole json response ? And also post ErrorResponse

Answer (score 0):

I would change the json to be in the following format when you send it back from the server. This will allow for a pretty easy conversion with Gson or another json converter.

This will give you an **ErrorResponse** object that will have a success boolean value along with a **List** that will contain whatever you return in the messages array. You could call it **errors** if you wanted too. You just have to update your annotations in the **ErrorResponse** class.

```
{
  "success": false,
  "messages": [{
    "type": "email",
    "message": "The email has already been taken."
  }, {
    "type": "phone_no",
    "message": "The phone no has already been taken."
  }]
}
```

Then I would create the following java classes:

ErrorResponse class

```
public class ErrorResponse {

  @SerializedName("status")
  @Expose
  private boolean status;

  @SerializedName("message")
  @Expose
  private List<Message> messages;

  ...
}
```

Message class

```
public final class Message {

  @SerializedName("type")
  @Expose
  private String type;

  @SerializedName("message")
  @Expose
  private String messages;

  ...
}
```